# How can I make user defined validation with ASP.NET validation controls?

Tags: asp.net, validation

On my FormView I have 4 attributes. User has to provide at least one of them. Is there any way to validate it with built-in ASP.NET Validators, or do I have to subscribe to ItemUpdating/ItemInserting events of FormView, then then validate is manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in validator for such validation. If you want to stick to framework validation control behavior you can place a [CustomValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx) on your web form and implement client and server validation routines.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to suscribe to itemupdating/itemInserting events of FormView and do it manually.

Comment: Or maybe you can use the control custom validator

Comment: You can find more information how to use it here: http://asp.net-tutorials.com/validation/custom-validator/